# Identify neon sign font in photo

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

just in case someone is able to recognize this, if not, doesn't really matter. I was browsing the web, came across a photo depicting an interesting font (RAMLÖSA, lower left corner). I like the placement of the umlaut on Ö. Sorry, I guess there is no higher resolution and the MyFonts.com identifier was not very successful either.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In signage, especially neon, there are manual alterations made so the functionality works. That's not to say a font with those off-angle umlauts doesn't exist. But chances are the sign manufacturer altered those specifically.

Comment: Not sure if you know this, but Ramlösa is Swedish carbonated water. This version of their logo is not found other places, so Scott is probably dead on. Neon signs does not conform to fonts.

Comment: .. and why the odd kerning around the L? :)

Comment: Thank you guys for the images and comments. The 'L' does seem to have and odd kerning, probably because it's "manually" made as @Scott also pointed out.

Comment: @Scott it is a bit odd, but not so odd in the dark, with the lights on ;) I tried to add the image of the lighted version, but it was removed - i will stick it back in, it certainly interesting to see the difference.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly still seems to much on the M side and too little on the O side :)

Comment: @Scott absolutely, but it looks _slightly_ less weird in the dark. This got me thinking about neon, and that is pretty cool in itself.

Comment: @Scott added a better night shot. It is worth noting that this is a classic neon sign from the early 30ties.

Comment: Broadly speaking, both branding and signage (in general) are typically based on hand lettering--especially anything pre-1960. Sometimes fonts are made based on the original hand lettering after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic neon sign from the early 30ties, adorning a central wall in Stockholm, Sweden. As @Scott points out above (I am merely trying to summarise) is that neon sign - particularly that old - tend not to conform to font faces. They are subject to practical problems, back then is was the literal bending of glass tubes. A difficult and at times dangerous job.

[image]

What is worth noting is that the letters do seem more *engineered* than *designed*, and this is the case: constructed. The kerning is a little odd, the R looks a little unbalanced. As the OP points out, it is a creative way of constructing ö, and it is likely that this is primarily for practical reasons.

So. It is not a font as such, it is a construction.

Answer (score 3):

In a case someone needs font close/resembling/similar to the letters in question (I mean the general size, not a neon wiring), it probably useful to place here this [link](http://www.myfonts.com/search/brandon/fonts/) and image -

[image]